# Google Cloud Functions not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having the next issue, my cloud functions just died.
My Firebase Cloud Function, calls a GAE Url, it stop working. When I checked the console the error was

***Error: cannot communicate with function. Function killed.***

I tried to re-deploy the functions but I'm not beeing able to do that. Every function throws the same error

***Deploy Error: Failure in the execution environment***

I really don't know where to look

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an outage on Cloud Functions, that likely also causes your problem. Check the status here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17019

**Update**: the problem has been fixed. See the status link for details.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep an eye on that and check again